# emacs fail on cygwin

Tags: emacs, gdb, cygwin

When I try to launch emacs on my win7/cygwin I got this error:

> ***MEMORY-ERROR***: [4856]: GSlice: failed to allocate 504 bytes
> (alignment: 512): Function not implemented

I have googled my error and it appear that gdb is causing it source: http://webapp5.rrz.uni-hamburg.de/SuSe-Dokumentation/packages/emacs/doc/PROBLEMS

I have just installed gdb so it might be the cause, so I have tried to uninstall gdb from cygwin using setup/"gdb"/uninstall but it dont seem to uninstall gdb
Any idea on how to fix my emacs problem or uninstalling gdb properly ?

Comment: Have you simply installed the Cygwin Emacs package, or did you actually compile it yourself? If the latter, your link seems pretty clear about it being related to Gtk+, so you should probably just specify a different GUI toolkit when running `./configure`. If you've simply installed the Cygwin package, I guess you need to report it to them as a bug? (or more likely there's an existing bug for you to look up).

Comment: I have take the setup file from their website, I tried to remove cygwin and reinstall it but it still dont work I even trying installing the 64bits cygwin in another directory and I have the same emacs problem, this is strange since cygwin only work on his own directory so the error should not repeat, or I am wrong ?

Comment: Someone will probably ding me for this, but I would suggest also asking on the cygwin mailing list: `cygwin@cygwin.com`. (Of course, that didn't help me much when I asked a question there recently.)  Maybe worth a try though.

Comment: Well I have leave cygwin to a virtual ubuntu, problem solved.

Comment: I have the same problem with cygwin64 after upgrading to 1.7.23 yesterday.

Comment: Why did you remove **cygwin**, if just its **emacs** is the problem? You could force to re-install your emacs using the cygwin setup64.exe. Also, did you check whether `emacs -nw` also produces the error message?